# Get the canonical path for a command

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

I'm writing a script that needs canonical path of certain commands. Since there could be symbolic links pointing to the actual commands, I use `readlink -f` to get the canonical path. But I'm not getting what I actually want with `readlink -f`, I'll explain with the following example:

Let's say my current directory is: `/home/user/Documents`
If I try to get a path of `sleep` with `readlink -f` I get this:

```
/home/user/Documents/sleep
```

What I actually want is `/bin/sleep`

Comment: Does `sleep` (either a file or a symlink) actually exist in that directory?

Comment: No, they are mostly commands (not in the script directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
readlink -f "$(type -P sleep)"
```

or if you're performance-conscious:

```
cpath="$(type -P sleep)"; [ ! -L "$cpath" ] || cpath="$(readlink -f "$cpath")"
```

Using `readlink -e` (existing) instead of `readlink -f` can save you from this kind of accident where you operate on a nonexisting file.

The second example assumes the path returned by `type -P` is canonical, which means it assumes your path doesn't have non-canonical components.

Comment: `[ ! -L "$cdpath" ]` is not a guarantee that the path is canonical or even absolute. The path could still be relative, and another of the components but the last may be a symlink.

Comment: Beware `which` has a number of issues. The standard command would be `command -v` (though would return the command name for those commands that are builtin).